# Why is the boundary of spectrahedra “more pointy” at matrices of lower rank?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, real-algebraic-geometry, linear-matrix-inequality, spectrahedra

In the following expository article about spectrahedra, it is established informally that the boundary of spectrahedra is “more pointy” at matrices of lower rank.

- Cynthia Vinzant, [What is a... Spectrahedron?](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/noti1116), Notices of the AMS, Volume 61, Number 5, May 2014.

Is there any formal statement related to this property? Is there in general, a relationship between the geometric dimension in $\mathbb R^n$ and the rank of the corresponding matrix?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Blekherman & Parrilo & Thomas's [Semidefinite Optimization and Convex Algebraic Geometry](https://books.google.com/books?id=O7hxRDy9vrIC)?

Comment: I guess by "more pointy" you mean that the normal cone at that point is larger? $\mathbb S_n^+$ has larger normal cone at low rank matrices, since a spectrahedron is the intersection of an affine manifold with the space of PSD matrices, then we expect a spectrahedron to be more pointy at these points as well.